# Ignore dependencies in Visual Studio SQL Schema Compare

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, data-comparison

Is it possible to ignore the auto-selecting of dependencies in Visual Studio SQL Schema Compare?

It's doing more harm than good - if I want to select a change in stored procedure with dependencies, it auto-selects the dependencies even if the difference is only differently set-up environment-specific variables. I can't see it in the `settings` window, but I might be just blind.